# Javascript to check if the page is loading inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a small website where the index has an iFrame where all the content (sections in the same website) is loaded. 
As I want this content to be cached and shown by Google and other search providers, I don't want to use metadata like NOINDEX NOFOLLOW for this content (almost plane text) pages, but I want this: **If people come to these pages in a full browser tab (that is: not inside the frame called #MainFrame) I want the page to simply redirect itself to the index.html**

What should I do, some help? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the iframe location is the same as the top window location:

```
if (window.location.href == window.top.location.href) {
  window.location = "index.html";
}
```

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY and even if I don't know so much of javascript, I can easily understand what's happening. Thank you a lot!!